# Gregorian Calendar Wrong Hour

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

So, I started to test around a bit with the Java-GregorianCalendar Class and noted a weird behaviour occuring, when initializing the Object with milliseconds. What bothered me was, although I set the milliseconds to 0 the time showed 1 o'clock.

After browsing StackOverflow a bit I noticed that Java sometimes gets confused with summer and winter time. So my question is, if although the time change was already done this year and we live in winter time again, this weird behaviour comes from winter and summertime.

Here is the Code I was  testing around with:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TestCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTimeInMillis(-3600000);
        System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        String format = "mm:ss";
        if (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 0) format = "HH:mm:ss";
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(c.getTime()));
    }

}
```

This gave me the Output

```
-3600000
0
0
```

The best thing would be to find a solution which is independent from substracting -3600000 as if on other computers this "bug" does not exist I dont want to have 23:00:00 :)

EDIT:

After trying a bit more out and thanks to the Feedback I was able to fix my little problem by just adding this line just after initializing the Calendar:

```
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with summer time and winter time, but with your timezone. Apparently you live in a timezone where 0:00:00 GMT corresponds to 1:00:00 in your timezone (like CET - Central European Time)

Comment: I am confused here.  What does “I set the milliseconds to 0” mean?  Where are you doing that?  Are you referring to -3600000 consisting of -1 hour and zero millisecons?  If so, why would that affect the Calendar’s hour in any way?  All that aside, what are you actually trying to do?  And since it looks like you may be trying to do date math, have you looked at the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) packge?

Comment: I mean if I do c.setTimeInMillis(0); the Output of c.get(Calendar.HOUR) is 1
Actually I am not trying to do time math but I want to get a right formated time out of seconds. So e.g. you have 20 seconds I want to display 00:20 as I need this for a game I program.

Comment: If you want to work with time only (without date, without timezone) the you're better off using `java.time.LocalTime` - `java.util.Calendar` is built to work with dates and timezones.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

**Problem:** You are mistakenly changing the date, not just the time-of-day. On top of that, a time zone is implicitly being applied.

**Solution:** Instead use the modern *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate
.now()                 // Better to explicitly pass the desired/expected time zone as a `ZoneId` object.
.atStartOfDay()        // Again, better to explicitly pass the desired/expected time zone as a `ZoneId` object.
```

Returns a `LocalDateTime` (**BEWARE:** *Not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline).

> 2018-11-01T00:00

Much better to specify time zone.

```
LocalDate
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland"  ) 
)                
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland"  ) 
)
```

Returns a `ZonedDateTime`. This *is* a moment, *is* a point on the timeline.

> 2018-11-02T00:00+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## `GregorianCalendar::setTimeInMillis` is *not* setting time-of-day

Apparently you mistakenly thought the `GregorianCalendar::setTimeInMillis` would set the time-of-day without affecting the date. Among the many flaws in these legacy date-time classes is some very poor choices in naming classes and methods.

But, no, that method redefines the moment as a count of milliseconds since epoch reference date of 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

Add in the time zone implicitly assigned to `GregorianCalendar`, and you have unexpected results.

> I started to test around a bit with the Java-GregorianCalendar

**Don’t.**

Those old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are *terrible*. They were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Specifically, to track a moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

> initializing the Object with milliseconds

**Don’t.**

Tracking time as a count-from-epoch-reference is prone to error. There are [many different epoch reference dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) in use in the industry. There are different granularities in use in the industry (whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds).

So a count-from-epoch is ambiguous. Also prone to confusing and missed errors because humans cannot read the meaning of the values.

When exchanging date-time values, use strings in standard ISO 8601 format instead.

When handed a count of milliseconds from the Unix epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC, parse as an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( … ) ;
```

## java.time

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes instead.

Get your date.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apparently you want the first moment of the day. By the way, do not think of this as “midnight” as that term is ambiguous.

The first moment of the day may not be 00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean that the first moment on some dates in some zones may be another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

Specify a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

If you want to see that same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Setting  c.setTimeInMillis(0); sets the time to  January 1, 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT (1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT) which is called the epoch

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis(long)

```
public void setTimeInMillis(long millis)

Sets this Calendar's current time from the given long value.

Parameters:
    millis - the new time in UTC milliseconds from the epoch.
See Also:
    setTime(Date), getTimeInMillis()
```

If you want to set the time to midnight, I think you want to do.

```
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: I actually knew *what* I was doing when initializing I just could not understand why I got 1 Hour as Output ^^
Thanks anyways :)